# Finding CustomerID by matching Customer.UserName to Logged On User

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

New to MVC3 Razor - linq to sql having spent some time trying to find how to:

Match the loged on UsersName to Customer.UserName and then select the Customer.CustomerID for the user.

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var CustomerID = from c in Customer
            where c.UserName = "User.Identity.Name"
            select c.CustomerID;

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the actual variable:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var CustomerID = from c in Customer
            where c.UserName == User.Identity.Name  //use double equals for comparison
            select c.CustomerID;

        return View(CustomerID);  //or whatever your view is -- some typed object?
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

YOur use of "User.Identity.Name" is wrong. You need to use the Property in HttpContext

In a more concise form, you could say

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
   var currentUser = Customer.Where(c => c.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
   return View(currentUser);
}
```